# Write Microsoft Word Doc with MySQL data

Tags: python, mysql, django, vba, ms-word

I'm programming a MySQL database with Web interface for remote access. I used Django as a framework. But now, I want to generate some reports using the MySQL data and modify them after generating. Therefore, I automatically think of exporting data to or importing from Word. The thing is, how I do this?

I have seen several options. One of them, using **Python-docx**, a library to generate docx documents in Python. I could have a problem with this, because the generated reports will be large, with lots of images, tables, pages, etc. I worked with xlsxwriter, and when the files were large it took long time to generate de xlsx. I don't know if **Python-docx** would be the better solution.

Other option is to import data directly from Microsoft Word, using some software for this concrete purpose or using a macro VBA. I have programmed some example code with VBA to import data of MySQL using connectors ODBC and it's immediately possible, but there is thousand of objects and classes of VBA Word to learn.

Exposed the problem, any tips or suggestions??? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please explain me why the negative point?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to generate HTML & open as a word document.

If you take a document similar to what you want to generate & save as HTML you will see what word does. Take this file as a template for your documents